# Security Trimming is not working in the SharePoint FAST Search 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

We have SharePoint farm with 1 APP server, 1 FAST Server and 2 WFEs. Our web application is having claim based authentication and we have two content sources to crawl contents. When search results are coming to the core result web part we saw that SharePoint pages are not filtered by the logged in users permissions. Logged in user can see any page in the search result page and then he/she try to access he/she is getting access denied.

Answer (score 0):

After so many troubleshooting session we were unable to resolve the issue and we contacted the Microsoft team to resolve this.

Finally, we were able to fix this issue as follow.

In Fast Search 2010, have a file called "qtf-config.xml" in the below path of the fast search box.

$DRIVE:\FASTSearch\etc\qrserver

This file is having a switch to enable or disable security trimming happening from the query server. In our environment, this setting was turned off and that is why our security trimming is not happening.

if you comment below line in the file you can disable the security trimming.

```
<instance-ref name="securityfql"    critical="1" />
```

You need to run below command if you change this file.

PS C:\FASTSearch\bin>nctrl restart